# I am trying to get a key and and a corresponding value from a Dart map but I'm failing no matter what I try

Tags: flutter, dart, hashmap

Here is the data; it's a list and one of the items (credit vendors) is a map of k, v pairs. I want to put each key and each value in their own Text widget. The code is below.

```
List<Blog> blogs = [
      Blog(
        title:
            "She changed religion to marry the man of her dreams- Hamidah and Efraim’s classy Kwanjula ",
        description:
            "Right after their arrival, Efraim and a select few of his entourage went right into "
            "Hamidah’s parents’ house for the basic session of kwanula: to be accepted and born into this home. \n",
        author: "James Arthur",
        date: "09 Jan 20",
        views: 3899,
        comments: 23,
        imagePath: "assets/images/intro.jpg",
        creditVendors: [
          {'Decorator': 'Parties & Events'},
          {'Photography': 'Paramount Images'},
          {'Food': 'Spectrum Restaurant'},
          {'Juice': 'Dalausi Juice'},
          {'Bridal': 'Sheena Collections'},
        ],
      ),
Blog(),
Blog(),
     
];
```

So I want to call creditVendors values within another class on a different page. Below is the code to illustrate what I am trying to achieve.

```
Container(
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: widget.blog.creditVendors.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext, int index) {
                        Blog blog = blogs[index];

                        return Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(blog.creditVendors.keys),
                            Text(blog.creditVendors.value),
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                )
```

Comment: can you share the Blog class?

Comment: I'm sorry I hadn't yet but now I have. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over maps by their values or keys. That won't be necessary since your `creditVendors` is an array itself.
Then you can use `ListView` widget to create widgets of your own choice from the values of the map.

Sample code

```
List<dynamic> creditVendors = [
  {'Decorator': 'Parties & Events'},
  {'Photography': 'Paramount Images'},
  {'Food': 'Spectrum Restaurant'},
  {'Juice': 'Dalausi Juice'},
  {'Bridal': 'Sheena Collections'},
];


ListView.builder(
  itemCount: creditVendors.length,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, int index) {
    return ListTile(
*emphasized text*             title: Text(
              '${creditVendors[index].keys.first} - ${creditVendors[index].values.first}'));
   }),
```

- You can get all the keys from a map using `mapName.keys` method
- You can get all the values from a map using `mapName.values` method

*Update*:

You have to use nested `ListView` since you iterating over two lists -> one is blogs array and inside that you want to iterate over that blog's `creditVendors` list.
Please see the demo code:

```
ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.blog.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, int _blogIndex) {
              Blog_blog = blogs[_blogIndex];
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _blog['creditVendors'].length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemBuilder: (ctx, int index) {
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                            '${_blog['creditVendors'][index].keys.first} - ${_blog['creditVendors'][index].values.first}'));
                  });
            }))
```

Comment: I am trying to call that class in a different class and this doesn't seem to work. I have to declare credit vendors as a variable within the other Blog variables. Assuming I have 100 blogs.

Comment: Kindly allow me edit my initail question with the code where I want to call values in creditVendors

Comment: @Ambrozekweronda You don't have to define creditVendor as another variable, I did here for demo purpose. You can call it like this `blogs[0].creditVendors `

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. So I have a home page with a list of blog cards. When you click on a card, it should bring u to the page of that blog article. So can I do this? widget.blog[index].creditVendors ?

Comment: Would you kindly help and edit that second section of my code to show me how it would look like?

Comment: One more issue but this is genius. The errors are gone but for some reason, the values are no showing on the emulator. I wonder what might be the problem.

Comment: And kindly forgive my ignorance, but isn't this  '${_blog.creditVendors[index].keys.first}' supposed to print a string for an int value? Or it's a different case for maps?

Comment: Also in which list builder is the scroll direction supposed to be? The outer or nested one?

Comment: Data is now showing but this error has persisted yet I have clearly added the item count parameter. The error is RangeError (index): Invalid value: Kindly help with this, please.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know that the blog list has only one elemet of type `Blog`

So I did it for only one element. If you have more just iterate rest everything will be same.

### You should do the following:

```
Blog a = blog[0]; //this will put the first element in a
```

### then:

define variables as maps because the content inside `creditVendors` is of type `maps`
and `creditVendors` is again a `list` data type.

```
// this is just to collect the data inside creditVendors.
  Map decorator;
  Map photography;
  Map food;
  Map juice;
  Map bridal;

  decorator = a.creditVendors[0];
  photography = a.creditVendors[1];
  food = a.creditVendors[2];
  juice = a.creditVendors[3];
  bridal = a.creditVendors[4];
```

Now:

you can access each map data as:

```
Text(decorator['Decorator'],)
Text(photography['Photography'],)
Text(food['Food'],)
Text(juice['Juice'],)
Text(bridal['Bridal'],)
```

---

**PS. CreditVendor is a list of Maps**

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help. Thanks a lot.